# Getting error Route not defined at LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, routes

I installed a Git laravel (employee-mgmt-laravel5.4-adminlte)

Now I'm trying to export an invoice to excel but the route doesn't work and I'm getting this error : Route [facture-management.export] not defined.

This my button

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('facture-management.create') }}">Ajouter factures</a> (this one work)
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('facture-management.export') }}">excel</a> (this one is not working)
```

This is my route

```
Route::resource('facture-management', 'FactureManagementController');
Route::post('facture-management/search', 'FactureManagementController@search')->name('facture-management.search');
```

What is going wrong because .create and .update are working but why is .excel not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your FactureManagementController you should have an export method.

and then: Route::get('your-url', 'FactureManagementController@export');

Because you have a resource route, you have the index/create/show/edit/update/destroy methods, but export you have to create.

If you do have it defined, please post your controller.

Comment: Thx for answer, Can you explain to me how i do that ?

Comment: define your route: Route::get('your-url', 'FactureManagementController@export') and create your export method in the FactureManagementController

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using a laravel controller resource. Laravel controller resource comes with the create and update function by default. You are getting this error because facture-management@export is not defined in your controller. Check your facture-management controller and see if public function export() exists. If not, you need to create one and define its functions.